# Python tornado redis - how to do a pipeline

Tags: python, redis, tornado

What is the proper way do to a pipeline in tornadoredis?  The documentation is not clear.  I am using the tornadoredis libary.

```
    import tornadoredis

    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    @tornado.gen.engine
    def get(self):
        self.pipe_threads = []
        sw = stopwatch.Timer()
        if not self.get_cookie('rtbhui'):
            self.cookie_id=str(uuid4())
            self.set_cookie('test', self.cookie_id, domain='rtb.rtbhui.com',expires_days=365*2)
        else:
            self.cookie_id = self.get_cookie('test')

        t = yield tornado.gen.Task(c.pipeline)
        yield tornado.gen.Task(t.set,'key', 'value')
        yield tornado.gen.Task(t.execute)



starting
ERROR:root:Uncaught exception GET /apixel?bid=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 (127.0.0.1)
HTTPRequest(protocol='http', host='127.0.0.1:8055', method='GET', uri='/apixel?bid=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', version='HTTP/1.1', remote_ip='127.0.0.1', body='', headers={'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Accept-Language': 'en-us,en;q=0.5', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0', 'Host': '127.0.0.1:8055', 'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8', 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:11.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/11.0'})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado-2.2.1-py2.7.egg/tornado/web.py", line 1074, in wrapper
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado-2.2.1-py2.7.egg/tornado/gen.py", line 107, in wrapper
    runner.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado-2.2.1-py2.7.egg/tornado/gen.py", line 319, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/rtbopsConfig/rtbServers/rtbTornadoServer/tornadoServer.py", line 81, in get
    t = yield tornado.gen.Task(c.pipeline)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado-2.2.1-py2.7.egg/tornado/gen.py", line 341, in run
    self.yield_point.start(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado-2.2.1-py2.7.egg/tornado/gen.py", line 223, in start
    self.func(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
TypeError: pipeline() got an unexpected keyword argument 'callback'
ERROR:root:500 GET /apixel?bid=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 (127.0.0.1) 6.69ms
```

Comment: did you figure out a way in the end? An update would be much appreciated. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Mybe it's a bit too late, but someone still may stumble upon this question.

When you use an `yield` statement with `tornado.gen.engine` and `tornado.gen.Task` wrappers you delay the execution of a code below the yielding point until the operation (that you've started in the `yield gen.Task(..)` statement) completes. In most cases you'll use `yield` statement to wait for a data trasfer completion.

The main point of using pipelines is to pack multiple redis commands to a single request to reduce a number of requests to the Redis server. So when you add a command to the pipeline nothing is sent to the server. There is no need to use `yield` statements at this point.

When the `execute` method is called, all commands, previously packed to a pipeline, are sent to the Redis server. It's better to wrap the `execute` method call with the `yield gen.Task()` even if you don't want to wait for the request completion to check the results.

A code using the `tornado-redis.Client.pipeline` method may look like this:

```
client = Client()
pipe = client.pipeline()
pipe.hset('foo', 'bar', 1)
pipe.expire('foo', 60)

re1, res2 = yield gen.Task(pipe.execute)
```

or you may use the 'with' statement:

```
client = Client()
with client.pipeline() as pipe:
    pipe.hset('foo', 'bar', 1)
    pipe.expire('foo', 60)

    res1, res2 = yield gen.Task(pipe.execute)
```

The pipeline feature uses the Redis transaction functions. You may read about them in this article: http://redis.io/topics/transactions

Answer (score 1):

In your case it looks, like `pipeline` function can not be used with `gen.engine`.

Have you tried to use `t = c.pipeline()` instead of `t = yield tornado.gen.Task(c.pipeline)`?